# Cloth keeps getting wrinkled and falling

Tags: cloth-simulation

I've been trying to create the cute poncho from the game **"Cult of the Lamb"**, to use during my streams.

However, since I'm fairly new to Blender, I decided to go for something a tutorial could show me, so I went for a shirt.

I've followed at least three tutorials, and I've done everything they did, with no falter. Still, the same thing keeps happening, and the shirt just gets crumbled and falls through. Please ignore the little ball, it's supposed to be the bell. [image]

Everything they tell me to do is to select the Cloth, go to Physics, and select "Sewing" under "Shape", and to click on my model, and add Collision.

Here are the Collision properties for the model

[image]

And here are the Cloth properties for the shirt.

[image]

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Hello please share your file (remove the useless parts)

Comment: Sorry about that. Had to search how to do it.

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=ZKmbbQdK" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/ZKmbbQdK/)

Comment: Merge by Distance the body topology, deactivate its geonodes modifiers (not sure why, you may know, maybe it createsbad topology ?), apply the Mirror modifier of the cloth, put the Quality Steps at 10, activate its Collisions and Self Collisions, put their Distance at 0,001, maybe increase the Quality of the collisions,it seems to work

Comment: Thank you! Thank you so much! This totally did the trick. It really was the geonodes. Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Merge by Distance* the body topology, deactivate its geonodes modifiers (not sure why, you may know, maybe it creates bad topology ?), apply the *Mirror* modifier of the cloth, put the *Quality Steps* at 10, activate its *Collisions* and *Self Collisions*, put their *Distance* at 0,001, maybe increase the *Quality* of the collisions,it seems to work.